# Why does gSOAP set stdin mode to binary if reads data from a file stream?

Tags: c++, xml, data-binding, xml-serialization, gsoap

I've been playing with gSOAP XML data binding by loading XML document into C++ class, modifying data and serializing it back into XML.

Here's the snippet of the XML - library.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<gt:Library xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gt="http://www.bk.com/gSOAP/test">
    <gt:Books>
        <gt:Book isbn="0132350882" author="Robert C. Martin" title="Clean Code">
            <gt:CopiesAvailable>2</gt:CopiesAvailable>
        </gt:Book>
        <gt:Book isbn="020161622X" author="Andrew Hunt" title="The Pragmatic Programmer">
            <gt:CopiesAvailable>0</gt:CopiesAvailable>
        </gt:Book>
        <gt:Book isbn="0201633612" author="Erich Gamma" title="Design patterns">
            <gt:CopiesAvailable>1</gt:CopiesAvailable>
        </gt:Book>      
    </gt:Books>
    ...
</gt:Library>
```

The following code loads XML into object, modifies object and serializes it back into XML. 
Note that XML is loaded from a file, via file stream and that data to be added is obtained from a user, via stdin (cin).

main.cpp:

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include "gt.nsmap"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::fstream;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

void DisplayAllBooks(const _gt__Library& library)
{
    cout << "\n\nDisplaying all books in the library:" << endl;

    std::vector<_gt__Library_Books_Book>::const_iterator it = library.Books.Book.begin();
    for(;it != library.Books.Book.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << "\nBook:\n" << "\tTitle:" << (*it).title << "\n\tAuthor:" << (*it).author <<"\n\tISBN: " << (*it).isbn << "\n\tCopies available: " << static_cast<int>((*it).CopiesAvailable) << endl;
    }
}

void AddBook(_gt__Library& library)
{
    cout << "\n\nAdding a new book:" << endl;

    _gt__Library_Books_Book book;

    cout << "\tTitle: " << std::flush;
    getline(cin, book.title);

    cout << "\tAuthor: " << std::flush;
    getline(cin, book.author);

    cout << "\tISBN:" << std::flush;
    getline(cin, book.isbn);

    cout << "\tCopies available: " << std::flush;
    string strCopiesAvailable;
    getline(cin, strCopiesAvailable);
    stringstream ss(strCopiesAvailable);
    ss >> book.CopiesAvailable;

    library.Books.Book.push_back(book);
}

// Terminate and destroy soap
void DestroySoap(struct soap* pSoap)
{
    // remove deserialized class instances (C++ objects) 
    soap_destroy(pSoap); 

    // clean up and remove deserialized data 
    soap_end(pSoap);  

    // detach context (last use and no longer in scope)
    soap_done(pSoap);
}

int main()
{

    //
    // Create and intialize soap
    //

    // gSOAP runtime context
    struct soap soap; 

    // initialize runtime context 
    soap_init(&soap); 

    // Set input mode
    soap_imode(&soap, SOAP_ENC_XML);

    // reset deserializers; start new (de)serialization phase 
    soap_begin(&soap); 

    //
    // Load XML (Deserialize)
    //

    _gt__Library library;   
    string strXML = "library.xml";

    ifstream fstreamIN(strXML);
    soap.is = &fstreamIN;                               

    // calls soap_begin_recv, soap_get__gt__Library and soap_end_recv
    if(soap_read__gt__Library(&soap, &library) != SOAP_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "soap_read__gt__Library() failed" << std::endl;
        DestroySoap(&soap);
        return 1;
    }

    fstreamIN.close();

    //
    // Display books before and after adding a new book
    //

    DisplayAllBooks(library);
    AddBook(library);
    DisplayAllBooks(library);

    //
    // Serialize
    //

    soap_set_omode(&soap, SOAP_XML_INDENT); 

    ofstream fstreamOUT("library.xml");
    soap.os = &fstreamOUT;

    // calls soap_begin_send, soap_serialize, soap_put and soap_end_send
    if(soap_write__gt__Library(&soap, &library) != SOAP_OK) 
    {
        std::cout << "soap_write__gt__Library() failed" << std::endl;
        DestroySoap(&soap);
        return 1;
    }

    fstreamOUT.close();

    DestroySoap(&soap);

    return 0;
}
```

After running this test application, everything is fine apart from all newly added elements have strings that terminate with a Carriage Return character (CR - `&#xD;`):

Modified XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gt:Library xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gt="http://www.bk.com/gSOAP/test">
    <gt:Books>
        <gt:Book isbn="0132350882" author="Robert C. Martin" title="Clean Code">
            <gt:CopiesAvailable>2</gt:CopiesAvailable>
        </gt:Book>
        <gt:Book isbn="020161622X" author="Andrew Hunt" title="The Pragmatic Programmer">
            <gt:CopiesAvailable>0</gt:CopiesAvailable>
        </gt:Book>
        <gt:Book isbn="0201633612" author="Erich Gamma" title="Design patterns">
            <gt:CopiesAvailable>1</gt:CopiesAvailable>
        </gt:Book>
        <gt:Book isbn="12345678&#xD;" author="Scott Meyers&#xD;" title="Effective C++&#xD;">
            <gt:CopiesAvailable>123</gt:CopiesAvailable>
        </gt:Book>
    </gt:Books>
    ...
</gt:Library>
```

I traced the source of the bug and found the following:

`soap_read__gt__Library()` calls `soap_begin_send()` which executes the following line:

```
_setmode(soap->recvfd, _O_BINARY);
```

`soap->recvfd` is set to `0` in `soap_init()` and `0` is a value of file descriptor of `stdin`.

Once `stdin`'s mode is changed to a binary, STL library does not parse `\r\n` to a single `\n` for read operations and `getline(cin, str)`, as usual, reads everything up to `\n`, copying `\r` into output string. And that is exactly Carriage Return character which appears in new strings in the final XML.

My question is: **Why does gSOAP modify `stdin` mode if the data source is a file stream?** Is this a bug in gSOAP?

NOTE:

As expected, if `stdio`'s mode is reverted back to `_O_TEXT` after `soap_begin_send()` but before reading data from `std::cin`, `getline()` works fine. Here is the patch:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_TEXT)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to avoid encoding problems when reading and writing Unicode and UTF-8 encoded XML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why would gSOAP *touch* standard input stream at all here? It reads data from a file stream (`soap->is->read()` is executed), not from a `stdio`. gSOAP leaves `stdio` in the binary mode after `soap_begin_send()` and never reverts its back to the default, text mode.

Comment: You do not need to modify recvfd to use the streams. The soap->is stream takes priority over soap->recvfd.

Answer (score 1):

Also this cause unwanted side effects! By using

_setmode(soap->recvfd, _O_BINARY); // found in stdsoap2.cpp

you always assume to read from a file or stdin, however if you set soap->is to a std::istringstream this isn't true.

Just assume you are using getchar() in your main routine, but on a thread you try to deserialize a xml from a std:istringstream (using gsoap xml binding). As result your program will hang. the only way around is to set soap->recvfd = -1;

Regards Ralph

Comment: Thank you for your post but it doesn't give the answer. We should not be modifying `recvfd` if we're reading from `std::istream` (`soap->is`). I posted this question to gSOAP mailing list and now am waiting someone to confirm whether this is a bug or not.

Comment: my program crashes when set `soap->recvfd = -1;` and otherwise it hangs as you have already mentioned. what to do?